# Wordpress category order not consistent with IDs

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I am building a site that is highly organized by Wordpress categories. There are two "types" of categories, one is just your average Wordpress category, the other is a category "Hospitals" with a list of hospitals as children categories.

A post can be assigned to a regular category AND a hospital. I am displaying the two types of category archives differently on two different templates. The problem is, some regular categories are listed before the hospitals, which is correct, but other posts have the hospitals listed before the regular category. So when I query the posts and get the category ID, I don't know if I am getting the regular category ID or the hospital category ID.

Here is an image of what I am referring to:

[image: Wordpress Category Issue]

As you can see, the top 2 posts have the hospitals listed first (Big Rapids Hospital, and Gerber Memorial) followed by the regular category. Where as a little further down the list you see Kelsey Hospital listed after "Heart and Vascular". This is what is happening when I query the categories as well. Some hospitals appear first, others second.

I am trying to use this custom function:

```
function get_cat_info($catInfo) {

    $cat = array();

    if(count($catInfo) > 1) {
        $cat['slug'] = $catInfo[1]->slug;
        $cat['name'] = $catInfo[1]->cat_name;
        $cat['id'] = $catInfo[1]->cat_ID;
    } else {
        $cat['slug'] = $catInfo[0]->slug;
        $cat['name'] = $catInfo[0]->cat_name;
        $cat['id'] = $catInfo[0]->cat_ID;
    }

    return $cat;
}
```

And I am calling the function on the pages using:

```
$category = get_the_category();
$cat = get_cat_info($category);
```

This works, but as I said I don't know which ID is being returned.

I reset my entire Wordpress database and re-entered all content and categories in correct order, meaning I put the regular categories first and then the hospitals so the regular categories would have a lower ID than the hospitals.

I thought that would help determine which category was being queried because it would either take the higher or lower ID, but it's taking higher AND lower IDs for different posts.

How can I make the order of these categories remain consistent?

Comment: Am I missing something? How could we possibly answer this without seeing your query and, perhaps, some DDLs?

Comment: WordPress's get_the_category() function returns categories in alphabetical order: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-order-of-get_the_category

Comment: @Strawberry The query is Wordpress's standard `get_the_category();` query. As you can see, I didn't modify that at all.  @PhoenixWing156 if you want to post that as an answer I'll gladly accept. Thank you for that bit of information.